# Add colon to the end of these two labels

Tags: html, css, forms

Here is the form code:

```html
<form method="post" action="https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/wp-login.php" class="bbp-login-form">
  <fieldset class="bbp-form">
    <legend>Create an Account</legend>

    <div class="bbp-template-notice">
      <p>Your username must be unique, and cannot be changed later.</p>
      <p>We use your email address to email you a secure password and verify your account.</p>

    </div>

    <div class="bbp-username">
      <label for="user_login">Username: </label>
      <input type="text" name="user_login" value="" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="101">
    </div>

    <div class="bbp-email">
      <label for="user_email">Email: </label>
      <input type="text" name="user_email" value="" size="20" id="user_email" tabindex="102">
    </div>

    <p><label>Security Question</label></p>
    <p>
      <select name="seq_ques[]" class="input" style="font-size:14px; height:35px;">
        <option value="16">"Sing Out Joyfully to Jehovah" Scripture?</option>
      </select><label>Your Answer<br><input type="text" name="seq_ans[]" id="seq_ans[]" value="" class="input"></label></p>
    <div class="anr_captcha_field">
      <div id="anr_captcha_field_1" class="anr_captcha_field_div">
        <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
          <div><iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6Lc061QUAAAAAHzXUIbnlghp8LcJD1x5EtlRfrQi&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucHVibGljdGFsa3NvZnR3YXJlLmNvLnVrOjQ0Mw..&amp;hl=en-GB&amp;v=66WEle60vY1w2WveBS-1ZMFs&amp;theme=light&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=1bfdqzy83l4n"
              width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-wtj5g7sxqs30" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe></div>
          <textarea
            id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bbp-submit-wrapper">

      <button type="submit" tabindex="103" name="user-submit" class="button submit user-submit">Register</button>


      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="register">
      <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1">

      <input type="hidden" id="bbp_redirect_to" name="redirect_to" value="?checkemail=registered"><input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="19d211952c"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/register/">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jvawo134/

My actual page is [here](https://www.publictalksoftware.co.uk/register/).

It shows a form:

[image: Register]

Is it possible using CSS to add **:** after the final two labels on **this form only**:

- Security Question
- Your Answer

---

I should give some context here. The two labels in question are injected from a WordPress plugin onto the form. So I can't add a class. based on the answer provided I can use additional CSS styling to get 50% of the work down:

```
.bbp-login-form fieldset p label:after {
  content: ':';
}
```

This will add the colon to the first label but the second label is more problematic. Looking at the code:

```
<label>Your Answer<br>
       <input type="text" name="seq_ans[]" id="seq_ans[]" value="" class="input">
</label>
```

See? We need to insert `:` just before the `<br>` for this label and I can't see that I can do it. At the moment, using the snippet above I end up with the colon after the input box.

## Update

Since the `label` is inside a `p` I had to use this styling for the first label:

```
.bbp-login-form p label:nth-child(1)::after {
  content: ':';
}
```

So that one works now.

## Update

Based on the comments provided I have added this further CSS that works:

```
.bbp-login-form p label:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 0;
}

.bbp-login-form p label:nth-child(2)::before {
  font-size: 16px;
  content: "Your answer:";
}
```

The side effect is that the final `input` box is now smaller in height.

## Final CSS

```
.bbp-login-form p label:nth-child(1)::after {
   content: ':'
}

.bbp-login-form p label:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 0;
}

.bbp-login-form p label:nth-child(2)::before {
  font-size: 16px;
  content: "Your answer:";
}

.bbp-login-form p input {
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

Comment: The "Your Answer" label is more complicated because it contains a `br` tag and an `input`.  I don't see how you can solve this one with CSS

Comment: This could work for the "Your Answer" label: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljw9zvs7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `::after` and set the `content` to a colon.

```css
.with-colon::after {
  content: ':';
}
```

```html
<label class="with-colon">My Label</label>
```

Since you do not have the ability to add a class to the labels, you have a couple options:

1. Check the injected markup and see if it has a class name you can target.
2. Use the `:nth-child` selector to target the third and fourth labels on the page like:

```css
.bbp-login-form label:nth-child(3):after,
.bbp-login-form label:nth-child(4):after {
   content: ':'
}
```

3. Or you can remove the colons from your other labels and then just target ALL labels in the form:

```css
.bbp-login-form label::after {
   content: ':'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The two labels in question are injected into the form via a Wordpress plugin. As a result I don't have opportunity to directly alter the `label` object and introduce a new `class`. Can this be done via "Additional CSS"?

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question. I think this issue here is the 4th `label` because of what is embedded inside it.

Comment: Target the `<br>` inside that label: `.bbp-login-form label br::before`

Comment: @JeremyHarris its not possible to add before to <br> like this

Comment: as <BR> break to new line :)

Comment: You would need something ugly like this for the second label: https://jsfiddle.net/Ljw9zvs7/

Comment: Oof, you are right. What about just manually changing the entire content of the label? Like target the label and with css set `content: 'Your Answer:<br>'`

Comment: I have did with js if @AndrewTruckle its work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use css for security question label

```
.bbp-email + p > label:after {
    content: " :";
}
```

You can use JS for Your Answer Label

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.bbp-email + p + p > label').html('<label>Your Answer:<br><input type="text" name="seq_ans[]" id="seq_ans[]" value="" class="input"></label>');

});
```

or you can add js directly to you functions.php

```
function add_this_script_footer(){ ?> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$('.bbp-email + p + p > label').html('<label>Your Answer:<br><input type="text" name="seq_ans[]" id="seq_ans[]" value="" class="input"></label>'); }); 
</script> 
<?php } 
add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer'); ?>
```

Comment: I don't know where to put that JS on my site.

Comment: OK give me second

Comment: `function add_this_script_footer(){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.bbp-email + p + p > label').html('<label>Your Answer:<br><input type="text" name="seq_ans[]" id="seq_ans[]" value="" class="input"></label>');

});
</script>

<?php } 

add_action('wp_footer', 'add_this_script_footer'); ?>`

Comment: put this code to your functions.php 

please use FTP.  or your can use any plugin for custom js

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/

this plugin you can us for add custom js.